# Install RPM package in a pre-built node image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rpm

I am writing a Node app I want to containerize using a pre-built node image (https://hub.docker.com/_/node/). I need to deploy application that I only have a RPM package for and I cannot figure out where to start finding documentation  or a small example to do this.

The examples I'm looking at use yum, which I don't have (from my understanding) in the pre-built node image.

```
COPY src/MyApp/lib/3rdPartyApp.x86_64.rpm ./3rdPartyApp.x86_64.rpm

RUN yum localinstall 3rdPartyApp.x86_64.rpm; yum clean all && \
    rm ./3rdPartyApp.x86_64.rpm
```

My other option is to use a CentOS docker image which has yum. But I'm running in to problems getting Node installed there trying to use NVM. But I'm also reading I shouldn't try to use NVM when building a Docker container and there is a better way.

Comment: Found a way to accomplish what I was trying to do and added it as an answer. Starting with a CentOS image instead (where I'll have yum and can install my .rpm) and using EPEL to install npm. Still not sure how to install a .rpm on a pre-built node image and would except if someone has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [alien](https://wiki.debian.org/Alien) to convert packages from one format to another.

```
FROM node

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y alien
COPY src/MyApp/lib/3rdPartyApp.x86_64.rpm ./3rdPartyApp.x86_64.rpm
RUN alien -d -i 3rdPartyApp.x86_64.rpm
```

This will leave a lot of extra files in your image. You can use two step build to clear it up.

```
FROM node AS builder

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y alien
COPY src/MyApp/lib/3rdPartyApp.x86_64.rpm ./3rdPartyApp.x86_64.rpm
RUN alien -d 3rdPartyApp.x86_64.rpm

FROM node

COPY --from=builder 3rdPartyApp.x86_64.deb .
RUN dpkg -i 3rdPartyApp.x86_64.deb && rm 3rdPartyApp.x86_64.deb
```

Comment: I ended up finding a deb for the 3rd party application, but I verified this worked before I found the deb. I think this is a better solution than mine for someone in the same situation as your final image has less installed to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM centos:centos7.6.1810

# Enable EPEL to install Node.js and npm

RUN rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm && \

    yum -y update && \

    yum install -y npm git && \

    yum clean all
```